# Ubuntu VM lose wifi internet from Windows 10 host after a while and

Tags: networking, ubuntu, wireless-networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine

Say I work from one WiFi for the day - after a while Ubuntu VM on Win10 host still shows an IP address but no internet anymore - it had internet when I started the day. Win10 has no internet issue.

It was working fine for a long time.
I updated the Oracle Virtual box - problem started - so I uninstalled and went back to prior version - now I have this issue. I fiddled with my Oracle VM software by turning it away from "Bridged" and came back to it, it started working again. What is the fix?

Also Ubuntu VM does not work off the work Wifi anymore - it used before the attempted upgrade to Virtual Box.

It is set up as Briged mode, allow VM and desktop. I read the forums and tried all the tricks but no luck. Wifi gives solid connection.

Answer (score 0):

If you have not tried yet, install latest version of Extension Pack on the host system, and Guest Additions on the guest system. Both should be always keep updated when you update virtualbox.

How to install Extension Pack:
Shut down your virtual machines, then download the installer 
https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads
and run.

How to install Guest Additions:
Run the virtual machine you want to install the guest additions on, then open "devices" menu and choose "install guest additions".

Comment: Thank you but it did not help.